# how to get all li elements has class show-skill in ul

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get all those li elements has class show-skill in ul, then I want to remove previous class and add new class to it, how can I achieve that.

```
<div>   
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
 </ul>  
</div>

<label> 
    <a href="#" onclick="get_li(this);">
</label>    

</div>

var abc = $(obj).parent().parent().children(':first-child').hasClass('show-skill');
$(abc).removeClass().addClass('new_class');
```

I have to go through the parent of parent way, Because there are many records coming with the same name, I want to make effect to the only one I click on not others and I want to have one code for all.

Comment: Begging people for upvotes is not appropriate behavior. Do not leave comments like this again.

Comment: I am not begging, my question is valid

Comment: It is not acceptable to ask people to upvote your question. Whether you think it is valid or not doesn't matter.

Comment: okey what should I do then if someone trying to stop me for learning

Comment: ***Nothing!*** A downvote does not stop you from learning. You should not ask anyone to vote for your posts in any way whatsoever.

Comment: now they will block my account and I have to go all over again

Comment: Your account will also be suspended if you keep asking for upvotes.

Comment: I am sorry I am not agree with you and I didn't like what you did, I know you down vote me

Comment: you are not a good person, sorry for that

Comment: @mohsin you're arguing with a site moderator (that's what the little diamond by their name represents).  You're also arguing against a *very* long-standing and widely accepted standard of behavior on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the updated code, Thanks

```js
function get_li(obj){
$('#'+obj + ' li').each(function() {
  if($( this ).hasClass('show-skill'))
    $( this ).removeClass('show-skill').addClass( 'new_class' );
});
console.log($('#'+obj + ' li'));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div >   
  <ul id="listEle">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
    <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
 </ul>  
</div>

<label> 
    <a href="#" onclick="get_li('listEle');">click</a>
</label>    

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbb1d1px/) for you.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
  <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
  <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
  <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
```

Test

**jQuery**

```
$(".myBtn").click(function(){
    $("ul li.show-skill").removeClass("show-skill").addClass("test");
});
```

I added a CSS class so that the change is observable.

**CSS**

```
.test{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the click function like this

HTML

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

jQuery

```
function myFunction() {
     $('ul li.show-skill').removeClass('show-skill').addClass('newclass');
  }
```

Or i would use the jQuery on click

```
$('.button').on('click',function(){
    $('ul li.show-skill').removeClass('show-skill').addClass('newclass');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.parent()` selector you're trying to use won't work in the given HTML, because the link being clicked on doesn't share a parent with the `ul` you want to manipulate.

Assuming that in real life there *is* a shared parent element, the best way to reach it is with `.closest()` -- chaining multiple `.parent()` calls together is very fragile, as it'll break if you change the HTML structure at all.    Same thing on the way back down: use `.find()` to get a list of all matching contained elements, instead of chaining together child calls.

```js
var get_li = function(anchor) {
  $(anchor)
    .closest('.sharedparent')   // gets container
    .find('li.show-skill')      // gets all contained .show-skill elements
    .removeClass('show-skill')  // removes class
    .addClass('new-class');     // adds new class
}
```

```css
.show-skill {
  background-color: #F00
}

.new-class {
  background-color: #0F0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sharedparent">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
      <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
      <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
      <li class="show-skill">sdfkjd</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <label> 
    <a href="#" onclick="get_li(this);">click</a>
  </label>
</div>
```

(Better still, if possible, would be to put a specific ID or classname on the parent element and make your call based on that instead of using relative DOM traversals at all -- the only reason to use relative traversals is if you have multiple containers that each should separately use the same behavior.)